# Find the last number in the given sequence

Tags: puzzle

Find the last number in the given sequence
$$\begin{pmatrix}
4& 9& 20\\
8& 5& 14\\
10& 3& ?\end{pmatrix}$$

(It's $3\times3$ matrix)

Comment: $\pi$.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: don't understand.

Comment: @PatrickLi It's a joke. Like in: What are the two next terms in the sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16? Answer: 31 and 57. Reason: $a_n$ is the maximal number of pieces you can cut a cake into with $n-1$ straight slices.....when the cake is convex, 4-dimensional, and with nonempty interior.

Comment: Unless you give us a condition for determining what a "correct" answer is, there is no correct answer.

Comment: @Asaf Sorry but you are wrong. Deadly wrong. How many times must I repeat that the answer is 42? Always.

Comment: @did: $\omega_1$ many times.

Comment: @Asaf Hmmm, seems a lot. Dunno how I am going to fit all these in my schedule. :-(

Comment: @did: Easily, fit zero times vacuously and the rest by a transfinite recursion!

Comment: @Asaf I see. Quite crafty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is $11$ since then $3 r_2 -r_1=2 r_3$  where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the three rows.

Comment: I think this is the intended answer.

Comment: $11$ is the likely intended answer: another route using the columns would be  $c_1+4c_2 = 2c_3$ as in my matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
4& 9\\
8& 5\\
10& 3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& \tfrac12\\
0& 1& 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Very clever answer! +1

Comment: How is that second matrix related to the problem?

Comment: It produces the first two terms in the third column of the problem and so is a possible solution to the question.  There are more.